# Don't consider space and tab as abbrev-expand commands, but keep the C-x whatever shortcuts intact

Tags: abbrev

I read the docs (at bottom) but can't figure this out.

I just started using "abbrev.el", and find that pressing
space,
tab,
C-x ', C-x a ', C-x a e
can cause the expansion to happen.

what if I find it dangerous for the expand to happen on tab and space,
how can I tell abbrev.el to not expand when pressing tab/space,

I still want to keep the ability to expand using "C-x ', C-x a ', C-x a e"

```
C-x ' runs the command expand-abbrev (found in global-map), which is
an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘abbrev.el’.

It is bound to C-x ', C-x a ', C-x a e.

(expand-abbrev)

Expand the abbrev before point, if there is an abbrev there.
Effective when explicitly called even when ‘abbrev-mode’ is nil.
Before doing anything else, runs ‘pre-abbrev-expand-hook’.
Calls the value of ‘abbrev-expand-function’ with no argument to do
the work, and returns whatever it does.  (That return value should
be the abbrev symbol if expansion occurred, else nil.)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `abbrev-mode` is on, it expands abbreviations anytime you
enter a character with non-word syntax, such as a space, a tab, or a period.

If you don't like that
behavior, turn *off* `abbrev-mode`.  Calling `expand-abbrev`
explicitly will still expand your abbreviations, and you can bind
that command to whatever keybinding you like.